# TypeORM NestJS ignore connection errors

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

Is there a way to ignore connection errors in the TypeORM NestJS module?

In my application I have 2 environments: in one of them I do use MySQL database (via the TypeORM), while in another I don't use any MySQL features, but still have to have it as a dependency because otherwise TypeORM will throw errors that it can't connect to the database.

I can differ the environments based on some variable, let's call it `isSelfhosted`.
Is there a way to ignore errors or don't connect to the TypeORM at all is this `isSelfhosted` variable is set to `true`, while still having some TypeORM related functions used in the code (which are called conditionally based on the specific environment)?

My current connection to the TypeORM looks like this:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ envFilePath: '.env' }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
      port: 3306,
      username: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
      password: process.env.MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
      synchronize: false,
      entities: [User, ActionToken, Project],
    }),
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    TaskManagerModule,
    AuthModule,
    UserModule,
    MailerModule,
    ActionTokensModule,
    ProjectModule,
    AnalyticsModule,
    WebhookModule,
    PingModule,
  ],
})
```

Thanks.

Comment: do you use a custom logger for your application?

Comment: @Oro yes, I do. Why?

Comment: Try to back to the default logger of nestjs. Maybe some problem with error method of your custom logger or something like that

Comment: On the env you dont use db, you can use  sqlite3 in memory database (it will always vanish from memory but still be present if any code tries to conenct or do something with database)

Comment: there is differents way to connect to the database on nestjs docs, the safe one is to create an ormConf.json, and I think to use multi-env, you can create a dynamic JSON creator to make it safe to switch between envs

Answer (score 0):

I use a function like that to generate json file, and don't use you env variable directly in the connect function

```js
    const generateOrmConfig = async (): Promise<void> => {
      const DATABASE_TYPE = 'postgres';
      const ORM_CONFIG_FILE = 'ormconfig.json';
      const ROOT_PATH: string = process.cwd();
      const pathToWriteOrmConfig = join(ROOT_PATH, ORM_CONFIG_FILE);
      const writeFileAsync = promisify(writeFile);
      const unlinkAsync = promisify(unlink);
      try {
        if (existsSync(join(ROOT_PATH, '.env'))) {
          config();
        }
        const env = process.env.APP_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV;
    
        const configTemplate = `
        {
            "type": "<%= type %>",
            "host": "<%= host %>",
            "port": <%= port %>,
            "username": "<%= username %>",
            "password": "<%= password %>",
            "database": "<%= database %>",
            "entities": [<%= entities %>],
            "subscribers": ["<%= subscribers %>"],
            "migrationsTableName": "<%= migrationsTableName %>",
            "migrations": ["<%= migrations %>"],
            "cli": {
                "migrationsDir": "<%= migrationsFolder %>"
            }
        }`;
    
        logger.info(`Current env is: ${env}`);
        const buildExtension = env === 'production' ? 'js' : 'ts';
    
        const typeOrmConfigObject = {
          type: DATABASE_TYPE,
          host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
          port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT,
          username: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
          password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
          database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
          entities: `"./src/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}"`,
          subscribers: `./src/**/**.subscriber.${buildExtension}`,
          migrationsTableName: 'migrations',
          migrations: `./migrations/*.${buildExtension}`,
          migrationsFolder: 'migrations',
        };
    
        const compiledTemplate = template(configTemplate)(typeOrmConfigObject);
        if (existsSync(pathToWriteOrmConfig)) {
          logger.warn('Orm config file already exists - lets recreate them');
          await unlinkAsync(pathToWriteOrmConfig);
        }
        await writeFileAsync(pathToWriteOrmConfig, compiledTemplate);
        logger.info(`Orm config has been created in: ${pathToWriteOrmConfig}`);
      } catch (e) {
        logger.error('Error occurs during ormconfig file creation');
        throw e;
      }
    };
    generateOrmConfig();
```